# Datas are getting displaying according to which month was created first

Tags: angularjs, sorting, widget, servicenow, angularjs-orderby

In a table I need to display the month data but while printing the data it should be displayed below its months header(jan month data should be displayed below jan but its displaying according to which time)

{{consumption_data.gen}} 
             {{consumption_data.supplier_site_name}} 
             {{consumption_data.oci_site}}   
             {{consumption_data.dh_cage}} 
             {{consumption_data.contractual_pue}}  
             {{consumption_data.lower_it_load_kw}} 
             {{consumption_data.average_it_load_kw}} 
             {{consumption_data.peak_it_load_kw}} 
             {{consumption_data.total_contracted_load_kw}} 
             {{consumption_data.load}} 
             {{consumption_data.contractual_pue_as_per_table}}

Comment: Hi, I'm not really sure what you are asking.  Is this an HTML table? a Glide table? a widget? a dashboard?

Could you reword your question with more detail?  Please include any code samples or screen shots that might be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: This is a wiget in servicenow , i need to fetch the data from table in display in the ui .
I could fetch the data from server side according to my requirement but while displaying the data the order is getting correctly .
The output should be in this format : https://i.imgur.com/Z6mB0er.jpg
But for me all the datas are getting printed in same row .Thanks in advance